# Bash script called from octave

Tags: bash, for-loop, octave

I'm using octave in order to create and execute a script. The script file is created successfully but it is executed correctly ONLY when I execute it from shell.

e.g. if I create the script file containing this line

```
for L in {1..5}; do > ${L}.txt; done
```

calling it from shell it creates 5 files
but calling it from octave (    using system("./myscript.sh");     or unix("./myscript.sh"); ) it creates only one file having name "{1..5}.txt"

My actual aim is not to create empty files, the above was just an example. In my script I'm using for loops which fail to be executed from octave.

Comment: I guess that's because octave does not allow brace expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Try "ps -f" to see which shell Your "myscript.sh" is executed under.

Try adding strict/enforced shell-specifier at the first line to tell it to run under bash.

E.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -f
for L in {1..5}; do > ${L}.txt; done
```

Comment: It was an ... idiot mistake. I've just forgot to put the #!/bin/bash in the beginning of the file. It works now. Thank you Vlad and @fedorqui